# Какое назначение элемента files в templateDetails.xml CMS Joomla?

Tags: joomla

Собственно вопрос в сабже. Была единственная догадка, что это нужно для редактирования шаблон из админки. НО оказалось нет. В независимости от декларированности файла в конфиге, любой файл можно редактировать.

Answer (score 1):

Описание структуры файлов и каталогов нужно для установщика шаблона, он использует эту информацию при хранении файлов во время установки.
https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Joomla!_templates#Folder_Structure

Comment: Хм. я думал он просто копирует все файлы из папки. Какая-то бесполезная вещь по-моему.